# @XmlAnyElement,DomHandler and completely unknown Xml

Tags: xml, jaxb, xmlanyelement

I have been following [Blaise Doughan blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html) .

In this example we trimmed only the `<bio>........</bio>` section . so the output is

```
<html>...</html>
```

Without the trimming the String looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><bio><html>...</html> </bio>
```

1. We are mapping the bio as an element , but why is it matched as a full xml ? (`<xml ..>`)

```
@XmlAnyElement(BioHandler.class)
    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }
```

2.In my case I don't have any predefined Tag for unknown Xml, So I don't know for sure what will be structure of my unknown Xml , So how can I get only the element section ? Every time I avoid the trimming code I get a small new xml inside my main xml .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bio>
        <html>...</html>
    </bio>
</customer>
```